# Roblox studio, can't place blocks in random position when round starts

Tags: roblox

```
local obs = game.ReplicatedStorage.Obstacles
local ob1 = obs.ob1
local ob2 = obs.ob2
local ob3 = obs.ob3
local ob4 = obs.ob4
local ob5 = obs.ob5
local ob6 = obs.ob6
local ob7 = obs.ob7
local ob8 = obs.ob8
local ob9 = obs.ob9
local ob10 = obs.ob10
local ob11 = obs.ob11
local ob12 = obs.ob12
local ob13 = obs.ob13
local ob14 = obs.ob14
local ob15 = obs.ob15

valu = true

while valu == true do
    basep.Size = Vector3.new(basep.Size.X - 0.5,basep.Size.Y,basep.Size.Z - 0.5)

    if basep.Size == Vector3.new(4, 5, 4) then
        local plrs = game.Players:GetChildren()
        for i = 1, #plrs do
            plrs[i].Character.Head.CFrame = CFrame.new(game.Workspace.lobby["spoint"].Position)
        end

        valu = false
        wait(10)
        basep.Size = Vector3.new(96, 5, 96)
        local plrs = game.Players:GetChildren()
        for i = 1, #plrs do
            local num = math.random(1,4)
            plrs[i].Character.Head.CFrame = CFrame.new(game.Workspace.teleports["part"..num].Position)
        end
        ob1.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(46,-46), -3.75, math.random(46,-46))
        ob2.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(46,-46), -3.75, math.random(46,-46))
        ob3.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(46,-46), -3.75, math.random(46,-46))
        ob4.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(46,-46), -3.75, math.random(46,-46))
        ob5.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(46,-46), -3.75, math.random(46,-46))
        ob6.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(46,-46), -3.75, math.random(46,-46))
        ob7.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(46,-46), -3.75, math.random(46,-46))
        ob8.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(46,-46), -3.75, math.random(46,-46))
        ob9.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(46,-46), -3.75, math.random(46,-46))
        ob10.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(46,-46), -3.75, math.random(46,-46))
        ob11.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(46,-46), -3.75, math.random(46,-46))
        ob12.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(46,-46), -3.75, math.random(46,-46))
        ob13.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(46,-46), -3.75, math.random(46,-46))
        ob14.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(46,-46), -3.75, math.random(46,-46))
        ob15.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(46,-46), -3.75, math.random(46,-46))
        valu = true
    end

    wait(0.1)
end
```

I wanted to do that when the round starts obstacles go to random x and z position from 46 to -46 and y stays the same, but i don't know why isn;t it working.Obstacles are just normal parts a bit resized.Need help quickly, and thanks to everybody who helped.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owWa3.png)

Comment: In order to see things in the world, they need to be in the Workspace, not in Replicated Storage

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but when i did change it and moved it to the workspace it still isn't working

[error that is showing up](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/705849375276138580/706135195467776071/unknown.png)

Answer (score 0):

### Main Improvement needed

Instead of doing

```lua
math.random(46, -46)
```

do

```lua
math.random(-46, 46)
```

and it will work much better.

### Extra improvements

1: Use `while valu` instead of `while valu == true`; this is for the sake of simplicity and readibility. Note that `valu` can be a string, and `valu` will be classified as `true` for the first loop start. Only if `valu` is `false` or `nil` will it be classified as `false`.

2: Try using `game.Players:GetPlayers()` instead of `game.Players:GetChildren()`; the function `GetPlayers()` returns only `Player` `Instance` objects, and not everything under `Players`.

3: Don't use `for i = 1, #obj` for this. Instead, use `for _, plr in pairs(obj)`, as it is more effecient. Also, instead of using `plrs[i]`, you can use `plr` when using this loop.

4: IF you use Player Choice, R15, or Rthro avatars in your game, use `Character.HumanoidRootPart` instead of `Character.Head` as this is better suited for modern character rigs. However, to deal with R6 avatars, use this script:

```lua
local plr = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
repeat wait() until plr.Character
plr.Character.PrimaryPart = plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart
```

That way, this works for all avatars.

5: Try to not have to get the same value over and over in a loop. Instead of using

```lua
for _, plr in pairs(plrs) do
    plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = CFrame.new(game.Workspace.lobby["spoint"].Position)
end
```

you should use

```lua
local Pos = workspace.lobby["spoint"].CFrame
for _, plr in pairs(plrs) do
    plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = Pos
end
```

This code is more efficient and doesn't index the same property over and over again too many times. For even better results, place the variable declaration outside of the `while valu` loop.
6: Don't repeat yourself too many times; use a function! Try doing

```lua
local function Pos()
    math.randomseed(workspace.DistributedGameTime) -- better random numbers
    return CFrame.new(math.random(-46, 46), -3.75, math.random(-46, 46))
end
```

outside of the loop, and inside the loop doing

```lua
ob1.CFrame = Pos()
```

### This makes your random numbers more random, and you don't repeat yourself! :D

Once you've done all of this, your script should be running great! Happy Coding!

Comment: forgot to add that i changed it a bit and here i forgot to put "local basep = game.Workspace.Baseplate" thanks for all of this that u write but if u would see this comment can you help how to do those obstacles that are just parts teleport to the map when the round starts and be in a random position from x 46 to -46 and from z 46 to -46

Comment: Thanks a lot pal

Comment: @niu No problem :)